# Laravel Sail + scheduler

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sail

Locally I have migrated my Laravel app from Homestead to Sail. Everything works fine except the scheduler.

My Commands which make calls to the database generate these errors in the logs :

```
[2023-11-07 08:50:02] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: Temporary failure in name resolution (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = my_database and table_name = workflows and table_type = 'BASE TABLE') {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: Temporary failure in name resolution (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = my_database and table_name = workflows and table_type = 'BASE TABLE') at /home/vagrant/code/my_project/back/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:801)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/back/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(951): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->runQueryCallback()
#1 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/back/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(930): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->tryAgainIfCausedByLostConnection()
#2 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/back/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(757): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->handleQueryException()
#3 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/back/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(407): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->run()
#4 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/back/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(394): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->select()
#5 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/back/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/MySqlBuilder.php(43): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->selectFromWriteConnection()
#6 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/back/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(353): Illuminate\\Database\\Schema\\MySqlBuilder->hasTable()
#7 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/back/app/Console/Commands/TestCommand.php(30): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic()
#8 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/back/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): App\\Console\\Commands\\TestCommand->handle()
#9 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/back/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(41): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#10 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/back/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure()
#11 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/back/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(35): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod()
#12 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/back/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(662): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call()
#13 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/back/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(211): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call()
#14 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/back/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(326): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute()
#15 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/back/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(180): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run()
#16 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/back/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1081): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run()
#17 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/back/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(320): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand()
#18 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/back/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(174): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun()
#19 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/back/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(201): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run()
#20 /home/vagrant/code/my_project/back/artisan(35): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle()
#21 {main}
```

The paths in the logs are showing the legacy paths from Homestead  (/home/vagrant/my_project/back/...). How can this be possible ?
The new Sail path is /var/www/html/...

I'm guessing the error might comes from that incorrect paths...

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check or update your DB connection in your Laravel app to match the new Docker containers? Asking just in case

Comment: Yes, and it is correct. My app can make queries to the database. I just don't understand why I get these logs when the scheduler runs.

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = my_database and table_name = workflows and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
```

query is incorrect, because you do not have quotes around `my_database` and `workflows`. This means that your schedulers passes these parameters without enclosing them into quotes. You will need to look into your scheduler or settings and fine-tune the query which will ultimately be generated.

EDIT:

It turns out (based on our discussion in the comment-section) that the query was actually correct, but @superfive33 was pasting it from the ORM log.

So, **Temporary failure at name resolution** is an error that happens when a hostname cannot be resolved into an IP address: https://tecadmin.net/resolved-temporary-failure-in-name-resolution-error-in-linux/

In such situations you need to check you internet connection (you already did so by sending this question), verify DNS settings (at /etc/resolv.conf ), check your hosts file (at /etc/hosts ) and compare them with your previous setup if it's still available. Clear DNS cache and restart the network service.

You can check whether the hostname exists via running

```
ping example.com
```

in your terminal. You might also need to authenticate to a VPN and check whether your database location has moved. Or you moved to a different network.

Comment: This query is generated by Laravel when calling `Schema::hasTable('workflows')` in my Command. My question is related to the paths printed in the logs (legacy homestead paths). Thx.

Comment: @superfive33 have you tried running this query directly in your RDBMS?

Comment: Yes and it works, because the table workflows exist in the DB. Again my question is not about the query itself.

Comment: @superfive33 no, you did not test it, at least properly. See this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c71e43/1 it already fails at `my_database`. Okay, let's assume that my_database was actually enclosed into quotes: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c71e43/3. See that the query fails because `workflow` is not wrapped into quotes. Your question is not about the query, but your query is **wrong**. Fix it first and let me know what is the next problem afterwards.

Comment: The query is printed as is by Laravel in the logs. But in the background, the query is ran with quotes, and it works. I haven't written the raw query, but instead I use the Eloquent ORM command `Schema::hasTable('workflows')`.

Comment: @superfive33 okay, thanks for the reply. Editing my answer with further information.

Comment: @superfive33 edited my answer.

Comment: @superfive33 I have just edited my answer. Is it really not helpful? You instantly replied with a comment, I doubt you have read it.

Comment: I read the edit and sadly it does not help.

Comment: @superfive33 I understand. I wish you success in resolving your issue.